# Circular button with an image in the middle

Tags: android, button, geometry

I want to create a circle button of radius 56dp. It should have an icon in the middle of 24dp and its a vector drawable so i should be able to specify the drawable tint

I created a button background as

```
shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:dither="true"
   android:shape="oval"
   android:layout_width="56dp" // is this same as 56 dp radius ??
   android:layout_height="56dp"
>

<solid android:color="?color1"/>

</shape>
```

And tried the button as below

```
<Button
                                android:id="@+id/xyz"
                                android:layout_width="56dp"
                                android:layout_height="56dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_background"

                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_drawable"
                                android:padding="16dp"
                                android:drawableTint="?color2"
```

So the icon is coming at the top and i dont see how can i keep it in the middle.
If i use android:src it comes in the middle but i cant give the tint. What would be the right approach

Comment: Here is one library that you can use to implement circularImageView  https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatImageView to solve your issue

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/border"
            app:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> android:layout_width="56dp" // is this same as 56 dp radius ??

You don't need to specify height and width to your drawable because it will auto adjust where it is used.

> So the icon is coming at the top and i dont see how can i keep it in the middle.

`android:drawableTop` will always put your image at top as it says.

> i cant give the tint

You can use tint in ImageView as below.

- I will not suggest you use ImageButton because it creates extra unwanted effect.
- I suggest use ImageView as button so because it is highly controllable view.

button_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

and use ImageView

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tint="@color/colorBlack" />
```

**Edit**

- For ripple effect on ImageView you can add `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` on ImageView for api level 21 or greater.

Comment: i need the button effect like ripple, elevation

Comment: If you can show required view, it would be better. I edited answer for ripple effect.